# Can I make the CSS :after pseudo element append content outside the element?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-element

I want to format a breadcrumb trail of links using an HTML `&raquo;` entity between adjacent links, so it looks like this:

> [home](http://www.stackoverflow.com/) » [about us](http://www.stackoverflow.com/) » [history](http://www.stackoverflow.com/) » this page

I've added a rule to my CSS:

```css
nav#breadcrumb-trail a:after {
    content: " » ";
}
```

but this is adding the entity INSIDE the link, instead of outside it - i.e. I'm getting this:

> [home »](http://www.stackoverflow.com/)  [about us »](http://www.stackoverflow.com/) [history »](http://www.stackoverflow.com/)  this page

Am I misunderstanding the behaviour of the CSS `:after` pseudo-element? Documentation seems to imply it adds the specified content **after** the specified element, rather than prepending it to the inside of the element's container. Any ideas?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Normally you code these menus as ordered lists anyway, so it makes sense to do something like this instead:

```css
#breadcrumb-trail ol { 
    list-style: none; 
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; 
}

#breadcrumb-trail li { 
    display: inline; 
}

#breadcrumb-trail li:after { 
    content: ' » '; 
}

#breadcrumb-trail li:last-child:after { 
    content: none; 
}
```

```html
<nav id="breadcrumb-trail">
    <h1>My Amazing Breadcrumb Menu</h1>
    <ol>
        <li><a href="">about</a></li>
        <li><a href="">fos</a></li>
    </ol>
</nav>
```

Comment: Also, `#breadcrumb-trail li:last-child:after { content: none; }`

Comment: Give that the order in which the pages are organized has semantic significance, I've used an ordered list rather than an unordered list - but otherwise this works perfectly (except in IE8, but meh)

Comment: I agree on the last-child stuff and the ordered list either. Thx.

Answer (score 36):

The [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#before-after-content) says:

> As their names indicate, the :before and :after pseudo-elements specify the location of content before and after an element's document tree content.

Note the key phrase at the end of this sentence, which refers to the inner content (or inner text). So, the pseudo-elements are inserted into the beginning of the end *within* the specified elements' **content**. Therefore the right double angled quote is being inserted **after the text** of your hyperlinks, rather than **after the hyperlinks**.

Here's a visual representation of the tree of the DOM element for one such link with both pseudo-elements:

```
a
  a:before
  content
  a:after
```

I guess one workaround to this behavior, is to wrap each link in a `span` then apply styles to `nav#breadcrumb-trail span:after`, but that'd result in unnecessary markup... worth a shot in any regard though.

Comment: There are proposals in the CSS3 Generated Content Module for an [`::outside` pseudo-element](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-content/#wrapping), but it is not known if it'll be deferred to a future specification or scrapped entirely, as this module is currently fairly low priority to most vendors.

Comment: This should be the correct answer, as it actually answers the question posed. I understand that kapa provided a good solution to the problem, but BoltClock's post actually answers the question.

Comment: @Luke So does the approach found in my answer below - even without additional markup.

Comment: In a sense, yes, except that your solution uses absolute positioning which places some fairly severe limitations on the user (especially considering the breadcrumb application in question) of the and doesn't at all address the expected behaviour of :after, something which BoltClock's answer does very well.

Comment: Finally, someone with a real answer to all these questions (this and all other related)...

Comment: It seems the names of these pseudo elements are unintuitive, and would be confusing to many users, especially those used to jQuery, which sensibly uses the names "append" and "prepend" for this sort of thing and "after" and "before" for what the OP was trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

Given the flexibility and [awesomeness](https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-E6ukbgTm5iM/Um0CrEtzXSI/AAAAAAAAG_8/-UoNFePQTcA/s1600/css_is_awesome2.png) of CSS, it looks pretty much do-able. Tried this in current Chrome, FF, and IE and it does the job just as expected, without the need to add addtional markup:

```css
#box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #eee;
  position: relative;
}

#box:after {
  content: '...appended text outside box';
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
  Some Box
</div>
```

Small Caveat: Absolutely positioned `elements are included in the boxes' dimensions, therefore elements floating or aligned next to it are unable to dynamically respect the width of the pseudo elements' content.

Comment: Indeed - this depends very much on your interpretation of "outside the element box" and your expected results. You'll simply need to position the pseudo-element manually - you cannot trigger a natural float layout or table layout or some such for example, since the pseudo-element box is always created as a child of the originating element box.

Comment: @BoltClock Very true, good point. I have added this limitation to my answer.

Comment: In the tree it is still inside the element