# CSS container pseudo element?

Tags: css, pseudo-element

In CSS, there are pseudo elements like "before" and "after". That creates virtual elements before or after an element.

**Container pseudo element?**

Is there a "container" pseudo element?

**Problem example 1:**

I need to create 15 borders around an element (I know this particular example can be done by using box-shadow).

**Problem example 2:**

I need to create 15 transparent background colors on top of eachother.

**A lot of unnecessary markup**

I know that is possible by adding containing divs, but that creates a lot of unnecessary markup.

Comment: Is there a question in there?

Comment: `::before` and `::after` are pseudo-elements, not pseudo-classes; and what do you mean by 'container' pseudo-class (I assume you mean pseudo-element, as with the other two)?

Comment: How exactly would a `container` pseudo class work?

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/4574946/886539

Comment: `::before` and `::after` create virtual elements before and after the *content* of an element, not the element itself - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5362811/can-i-make-the-css-after-pseudo-element-append-content-outside-the-element/5362843#5362843

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The old [CSS3 Generated and Replaced Content Module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-content/#wrapping) had a proposal for an `::outside` pseudo-element which seems close to what you describe, but there are no implementations, and the module itself is slated for a rewrite... someday.

In other words, there's currently no way to achieve this using only CSS, and there probably won't be any for a while.

Of course, there are ways to emulate wrapping elements using JavaScript to manipulate the DOM, but that's just about the only way you can achieve this besides hardcoding in the extra markup. Some trivial jQuery methods with respect to the fabled `::outside` pseudo-element are described here:

[Enable support for CSS3 ::outside pseudoelement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10419614/enable-support-for-css3-outside-pseudoelement)

Comment: And no one browser want to implement full support after 9 years. Author of this module = author of ACID tests.