# Wrapping CSS pseudo-element

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Is it possible to simulate a div around **b** and **c** items and to style it without changing this HTML?

I know there are `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements but couldn't find any "wrapping" element. Maybe something like `::wrap(.b, .c)`.

```
<ul>
    <li class="a">a</li>
    <li class="b">b</li>
    <li class="c">c</li>
    <li class="d">d</li>
</ul>
```

A good example could be isolating and putting a single background image behind **b** and **c**.

Comment: Removed the "border" case. Intention is to group elements and not to put a border. Background image can be a good example if no specific solution is given for that.

Comment: There are no wrapping pseudo-elements.  And adding a wrapper element to `.b` and `.c` (manually or with JavaScript) is impossible, because only `li` is valid as a child of `ul`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS container pseudo element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11586192/css-container-pseudo-element)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `border` property and apply it to the `b` and `c` class:

```
li.b {
    border:1pt solid black;
}

li.c {
    border:1pt solid black; 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ykjv16d8/1/

**From your comments:**

You can set the `border-bottom` to `none` for `b` and the `border-top` to `none` for `c`

```
li.b {
    border:1pt solid black;
    border-bottom: none;
}

li.c {
    border:1pt solid black; 
    border-top:none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ykjv16d8/2/

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't you just do something like,

```
li.c,li.b { border: 1px solid black; }
```

Comment: Sorry I was not clear and just made an edit. I mean one border around both but my intention is not the border itself. I want to simulate a div around them.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming no margin between list items, this will work:

```css
li.b, li.c {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

li.b {
  border-bottom: none;
}

li.c {
  border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li class="a">a</li>
    <li class="b">b</li>
    <li class="c">c</li>
    <li class="d">d</li>
</ul>
```

If there *are* margins, you'll need to be a bit more creative:

```css
li {
  margin: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

li.b::before, li.c::before {
  content: '';
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% + 20px);
  top: -10px;
  left: -2px;
}

li.b::before {
  border-bottom: none;
}

li.c::before {
  border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li class="a">a</li>
    <li class="b">b</li>
    <li class="c">c</li>
    <li class="d">d</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is not (currently) a solution for this using good old CSS psuedo elements.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you want both b and c to be in one box??

try this

html

```
<ul>
  <li class="a">a</li>
  <li class="b bc">b</li>
  <li class="c bc">c</li>
  <li class="d">d</li>
</ul>
```

css

```
.bc {
   border: 1px solid red;
 }

.b.bc {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.c.bc {
 border-top: none;
}
```

is that what you mean? let me know

Comment: I confused everybody asking to put a border. I need to simulate a div around them without changing html. Try to put a background image using the same solution.